# How to start Angular app without installing it to the project

Tags: angular

I was given a coding assessment for a potential job. One of the 3 tasks involves debugging an Angular app. I have no experience in Angular (I studied React) and am having trouble just getting the app to run.

I globally installed both angular and angular-cli. Running ng serve gives me the error: "You seem to not be depending on "@angular/core". This is an error."

I believe this happens because Angular is not installed to the project, but instead is in the project as a single angular.js file. There is no node_modules folder or package.json file. The structure of the project is all in one folder:

```
-angular.js
-app.js
-index.html
-style.css
```

Comment: That seems like the first task in your assignment. What I would do is to take a look at how a minimal Angular app looks like and compare them.

Comment: This is an `Angular JS` project. Navigate to this folder in your terminal and start `http-server` to run the project.

Comment: Are you sure it is `angular` and not `angularjs`? If you were given those files then its either `angularjs` **or** a compiled version of the `angular` sources. Either way you can't add those to a new `angular` project (*although you could use the upgrade module for `angularjs`*)

Comment: I am such an angular beginner I wasn't even aware there was a difference between angular and angularjs. I installed and ran http-server from that folder and now I can at least run the application. Now to dive deeper and see if I can actually fix the bugs. Thanks for the quick help.